# JavaScript setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, onload

I wanted a JavaScript function to run 60 seconds after page is loaded.
After a little research I have made, I've found that setTimeout() is the solution.

So that's what I did:

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout(postAction('news.reads', 'article'), 60000);">
```

Somehow, setTimeout does not work. After the page is loaded, there's no need to wait 60 seconds because postAction() runs immediately.

Why is it happening? How to solve it? Are there alternatives to setTimeout() up there?
Thank you!

Comment: Umm some code samples please...

Comment: It could be anything: are you passing `postAction` or `postAction()` as a first argument to `setTimout`? the second is _wrong_. Are you passing a string as a first argument? Don't. The timeOut is specified in milliseconds, not seconds: 60 seconds is, thus, written as 60000

Comment: Sorry, I posted my code earlier, but forgot to mark it as "code", so it was removed... Now I added the code sample again.

Comment: You're not calling the function after 60 seconds with your snippet, you're calling _the return value of the function_: `postAction(argument, argument)` is a function call, whatever it returns is what `setTimeout` will try to execute after 60 seconds. Most likely, this will be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do what you want in JS, ie setting a timeout *after* the page is loaded:

```
(function(w)
{
    var load = function()
    {
         setTimeout(postAction,60000);
         if (w.removeEventListener)
         {//remove listeners, to avoid leak...
             return w.removeEventListener('load',load,false);
         }
         return w.attachEvent('onload',load);
    };
    if (w.addEventListener)
    {
        return w.addEventListener('load',load,false);
    }
    return w.attachEvent('onload',load);
}(this));
```

Instead of `window.onload = function(){setTimeout(postAction,60000);};`, which will work, too, but cause a mem-leak in IE <9. That's just for completeness' sake
Anyway, the key line here is `setTimeout(postAction,60000);`

*Update*
After seeing the code you're using, this is the easiest fix:

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout(function(){ return postAction('news.reads', 'article');}, 60000);">
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to wrap `postAction` in a function to defer execution:

```
setTimeout(function() { postAction('news.reads', 'article'); }, 60000);
```

You are actually executing `postAction` immediately, your code is equivalent to:

```
var result = postAction('news.reads', 'article');

setTimeout(result, 60000);
```

Comment: Clean and apt.. Thanks :)

Comment: thanx worked for me too +1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `setTimeout` like :

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("OK");}, 1000 * 60); // alert "OK" in 60s
```

Comment: I am:
`<body onLoad="setTimeout(postAction('news.reads', 'article'), 60000);">`

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
        function doSomeJavascript() {
            // javascript code goes here
           alert('5 secs is up!');
        }
        // calls function doSomeJavascript() 5 secs after page load
        var interval = setInterval(doSomeJavascript, 5000);

        setTimeout(function() {
           window.clearInterval(interval);
        }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: NOOOO `setInterval` without assigning the interval id... that's just wrong! this creates an infinite loop! Go on @Martin, I dare you to paste this code in your console:)

Comment: Yes but not too far to go to prevent that.

Comment: Sorry, but this gets -1: first suggestion caused an infinite loop, and your suggested solution is setting a global variable - just use `setTimeout`, that's what it's for

Comment: OK, bed time for me I guess :(